# How to write a data-file with specific pattern?

Tags: python

I have to write a python data file that has the following format:

**count, id, type, x, y, z**

- **count** is basically the number of lines so its count = +1.
- **x, y, z** are basically the coordinates for a system and I extract it from a function in the script.

Problem is with:

- **id** - this value should stay same for three consecutive lines.
- **type** - should alternate between 1 and 2 but follow a 122 pattern as shown below.

Example of a few lines of how the data file will look:

```
1, 1, 1, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0
2, 1, 2, 0.1, 1.1, 2.1
3, 1, 2, 0.2, 1.2, 2.2
4, 2, 1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5
5, 2, 2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7
6, 2, 2, 0.8, 0.7, 0.9
```

As you can see the **id** stays the same for 3 instances and then changes by +1.

And the **type** follows a 122 pattern in the column.

The part I require help with is a loop which can help define the **id** and **type** columns in a single `fout` line. Not sure if this makes the problem more clear.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The problem seems feasible with loops. Maybe that's a starting point for you.

Comment: Okay, so what is the actual question, the actual difficulty? Are you able to open a file? Are you able to write lines to the file? For any given coordinate, can you state a rule that computes each value that should appear on the line? Can you repeat this process for each coordinate? *Which part of this do you need help with?*

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please show what you have tried and where the problem lies. SO is not a free coding service. As a hint though, you might want to check out the pandas library, it should be rather easy to achive with it. If you show some actual code and effort to solve it yourself first, there will propably be plenty of people willing to help. ALso split your question into multiple much simpler questions which is helpful for future readers, because its unlikely they have the exact same problem but more likely they want to know e.g. about repeating values like your 122

Comment: @Andreas: Apologies, should I post the code in the original question to make it more clear? Am new to both python and SO and so I don't know how exactly to phrase the question tbh

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Yes, the data file in previous version without the 'id' and 'type' columns was working well. I am pretty new to Python and only using it to write the file using it , so am not very knowledgeable on loops which I feel is the method to get the pattern am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
total_count = 12 #you can modify accordingly
id = 0
for i in range(total_count):
    if (i+1)%3 == 1:
      id = id + 1
      print((i+1), id, 1, "val1", "val2", "val3")
    else:
      print((i+1), id, 2, "val1", "val2", "val3")
```

In the above script, you can replace x, y, z values in val1, val2, val3 resp on the go.

Output

```
(1, 1, 1, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3')
(2, 1, 2, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3')
(3, 1, 2, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3')
(4, 2, 1, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3')
(5, 2, 2, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3')
(6, 2, 2, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3')
(7, 3, 1, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3')
(8, 3, 2, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3')
(9, 3, 2, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3')
(10, 4, 1, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3')
(11, 4, 2, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3')
(12, 4, 2, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3')
```

Comment: you're a legend man, it worked on first try. Thank you so much !!